# scp with sshpass - remote directory and file with wildcards

Tags: ssh, wildcards, scp

I have a list with 950 MongoDB VMs

I wish to collect all mongodb.log. The path to log file is depending on database name.

```
for i in $(cat /tmp/mongonodes.txt) ; do sshpass -p34dDgdWger@rg4fll434ef scp root@$i:/data/*replicaset/*replicaset*/mongodb.log /tmp/$i-mongodb.log; done
```

The above command doesen't work. I can't signle quote the `root@$i:/data/*replicaset/*replicaset*/mongodb.log` because of variable hostname.

SSH keys are not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Escaping SSH:

- Consider moving data over SSH, escaping `*` using `\` or `""` (quotes). You don't need to escape the variable, just the scp host:"path\ *" for example. You may need to escape it twice.

Example, using `\*`:

```
# On server (created a test log to replicate your scenario):
mkdir -p /data/TEST1replicasetTEST2/TEST3replicasetTEST4
touch /data/TEST1replicasetTEST2/TEST3replicasetTEST4/mongodb.log

# On client (I already have ssh keys, but sshpass will work all the same):
for i in $(cat /tmp/mongonodes.txt)
do 
    scp cmihai@$i:/data/\*replicaset\*/\*replicaset\*/mongodb.log \ 
       /tmp/$i-mongodb.log
done
```

Result:

```
mongodb.log                                   100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00

$ ls /tmp/*mongo*
/tmp/192.168.136.148-mongodb.log  /tmp/mongonodes.txt
```

## Short term:

- Setup `SSH keys` and distribute them to your servers (ex: [ssh-copy-id](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/ssh-copy-id.1.html))

## Medium term:

- Consider using configuration management software such as [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) or [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/)

## Long term:

- Look at a centralized logging (such as [syslog](https://syslog-ng.org/))
- Distributed log collectors such as [Flume](https://flume.apache.org/)

## Reference:

- http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2012/01/03/centralized-logging/
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-linux-unix/
- http://www.howtogeek.com/66776/how-to-remotely-copy-files-over-ssh-without-entering-your-password/

PS: don't paste your password here :-).